# Как отфильтровать с заменой значения?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных, фильтрация

Есть DataFrame (таблица) типа:

```
Номер  Столбец 1
    1        120
    2         80
    3         40
    4         30
    5        150
    6         60
```

Нужно значениям в столбце `Столбец 1`, которые больше 100, присвоить 100.

Comment: И где у вас возникли затруднения?

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не знаю какой метод подобрать. Новичок. Думал перебором, но тоже не уверен. Про pandas мало литературы.

Comment: Все, вроде решил перебором:

Comment: for i, item in enumerate(ap_hi):
    if ap_hi[i] > 450:
        ap_hi[i] = 450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот несколько **векторизированных** (быстрых, без использования циклов) вариантов:

```
df['Столбец 1'] = df['Столбец 1'].clip(upper=100)
```

или

```
df.loc[df['Столбец 1'] > 100, 'Столбец 1'] = 100
```